# Number of non decreasing sequences of length $M$

Tags: combinatorics

How many non decreasing sequences are there of length $M$, provided the number in the sequences are allowed from $1,2,3,...,N$?

Comment: Are repetitions allowed?

Comment: Since (s)he said non decreasing, I guess repetitions are allowed.

Answer (score 7):

Elaborating **user2255279**'s answer:

For $k=1,2,3 \cdots N$, let $k$ appear $n_k$ number of times in a particular allowed $M$ length sequence.

Since we want the $M$ length sequence to be non decreasing, $n_1$ number of $1$s have to appear at the start of the sequence, followed by $n_2$ number of $2$s and so on. Thus the set of numbers $n_k$ uniquely determines an allowed sequence.

So it remains to count the number of sets of allowed $n_k$s. The only constraint is the length of the sequence is $M$.

Therefore the number of non-negative integer solutions to $n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_N = M$ is the answer to your question. By [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), the answer is $\binom{N+M-1}{M}$.

**Abhra Abir Kundu**'s answer matches the above if you write $\dbinom{M-1}{r-1}$ as $\dbinom{M-1}{M - r}$ and then use [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

The answer is $\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{M}{N \choose r}{M-1 \choose r-1}$

Reason as hints:

Hint 1:How many distinct numbers can be there?Can it be $>$ M ?

Hint 2:Consider you select some $M$ numbers from the given set .How many distinct sequences can be formed with it?

Hint 3:For each set of distinct $r$ numbers with $(r\le ...)$ how many $M$ termed sequences can you form out of this $r$ distinct numbers.(Let $p_1,p_2,\dots p_r$ be the selected numbers and let each $p_i$ occur $x_i\ge 1$ times then we have $x_i+x_2+x_3\dots +x_r=M$.Now think of the number solutions of this equation.)

We also have,

$\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{M}{N \choose r}{M-1 \choose r-1}={N+M-1 \choose N-1}={N+M-1 \choose M}$(why?)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Instead of $a_n$, consider $b_n=n+a_n$

Comment: If we're giving the game away, $\{b_n\}$ is a subset of the numbers from 2 to $N+M$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this was easy!

Number of ways form one to one correspondence with the solutions of

x1 + x2 + .... + xN = M.