# Formula for number of monotonically decreasing sequences of non-negative integers of given length and sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, integers, integer-partitions

What is a formula for number of monotonically decreasing sequences of non-negative integers of given length and sum?  For instance, if length k=3 and sum n=5, then these are the 5 sequences that meet the criteria...

- 5, 0, 0
- 4, 1, 0
- 3, 2, 0
- 3, 1, 1
- 2, 2, 1

I have some [code](https://github.com/jmegner/KT21Calculator/blob/7e52c9cffe9d077b6282c739afc2b83c858325a8/src/CalcEngineCommon.ts#L385-L415) that given a monotonically decreasing sequence, produces the next monotonically decreasing sequence with same length and sum.

Here is a table of number of these monotonically decreasing sequences of non-negative integers for various lengths and sums ...

| length | sum1 | sum2 | sum3 | sum4 | sum5 | sum6 | sum7 | sum8 | sum9 | sum10 | sum11 | sum12 | sum13 | sum14 | sum15 | sum16 | sum17 | sum18 | sum19 | sum20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 9 | 9 | 10 | 10 | 11 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 10 | 12 | 14 | 16 | 19 | 21 | 24 | 27 | 30 | 33 | 37 | 40 | 44 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 9 | 11 | 15 | 18 | 23 | 27 | 34 | 39 | 47 | 54 | 64 | 72 | 84 | 94 | 108 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 10 | 13 | 18 | 23 | 30 | 37 | 47 | 57 | 70 | 84 | 101 | 119 | 141 | 164 | 192 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 14 | 20 | 26 | 35 | 44 | 58 | 71 | 90 | 110 | 136 | 163 | 199 | 235 | 282 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 21 | 28 | 38 | 49 | 65 | 82 | 105 | 131 | 164 | 201 | 248 | 300 | 364 |
| 8 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 22 | 29 | 40 | 52 | 70 | 89 | 116 | 146 | 186 | 230 | 288 | 352 | 434 |
| 9 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 22 | 30 | 41 | 54 | 73 | 94 | 123 | 157 | 201 | 252 | 318 | 393 | 488 |
| 10 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 22 | 30 | 42 | 55 | 75 | 97 | 128 | 164 | 212 | 267 | 340 | 423 | 530 |
| 11 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 22 | 30 | 42 | 56 | 76 | 99 | 131 | 169 | 219 | 278 | 355 | 445 | 560 |
| 12 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 22 | 30 | 42 | 56 | 77 | 100 | 133 | 172 | 224 | 285 | 366 | 460 | 582 |
| 13 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 22 | 30 | 42 | 56 | 77 | 101 | 134 | 174 | 227 | 290 | 373 | 471 | 597 |
| 14 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 22 | 30 | 42 | 56 | 77 | 101 | 135 | 175 | 229 | 293 | 378 | 478 | 608 |
| 15 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 22 | 30 | 42 | 56 | 77 | 101 | 135 | 176 | 230 | 295 | 381 | 483 | 615 |
| 16 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 22 | 30 | 42 | 56 | 77 | 101 | 135 | 176 | 231 | 296 | 383 | 486 | 620 |
| 17 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 22 | 30 | 42 | 56 | 77 | 101 | 135 | 176 | 231 | 297 | 384 | 488 | 623 |
| 18 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 22 | 30 | 42 | 56 | 77 | 101 | 135 | 176 | 231 | 297 | 385 | 489 | 625 |
| 19 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 22 | 30 | 42 | 56 | 77 | 101 | 135 | 176 | 231 | 297 | 385 | 490 | 626 |
| 20 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 22 | 30 | 42 | 56 | 77 | 101 | 135 | 176 | 231 | 297 | 385 | 490 | 627 |

Relatedly, if we remove the "monotonically decreasing" requirement, then the answer would be the "combinations with replacement" formula:

$\frac{(sum + length - 1)!}{sum! \cdot (length - 1)!}$

And if I remove the "sum" requirement, I think there are some existing posts, like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432496/number-of-non-decreasing-sequences-of-length-m).

Comment: I think you meant sum $=5$ in your example, not $4$.

Comment: This is often written as $p_k(n)$ where $k$ is the length and $n$ is the sum. These are the paritions of length $k$ of $n.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: There aren't good closed formula for most partition counting. Certainly, that Wikipedia page gives no good formula for $p_k(n),$ just a recursive formula.

Comment: Probably better link for $p_k(n),$ so it is not buried in the general article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_of_partition_numbers

Comment: @lulu, yes, thanks, I did mean sum=5.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks! Reading and digesting...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, with memoization, the recurrence relation is much moreefficient than generating the sequences themselves.  A quick code-up with memoization got ~551 recursions for {sum=32, length=15}, which is close to the `32*15 = 480` I would expect, and much smaller than the 7434 number of sequences themselves.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If you copy-paste to a answer, I would be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to the number of integer partitions of $n$ of length $k,$ and is usually denoted $p_k(n).$ There isn't a known  closed form,but there is a recursion:

$$p_k(n)=p_k(n-k)+p_{k-1}(n-1).$$

There are also generating functions for $p_k(n).$

Wikipedia page for [this function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_of_partition_numbers)

Wikipedia page [more generally about integer partitions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))